# "translation of" or "translation for"

Tags: prepositions

What's the correct form?
Examples:

- What's the translation **of** "whatever" in Portuguese?

Or

- What's the translation **for** "whatever" in Portuguese?

Are both correct? I've seen both in many texts (including this site), but I never know which one is correct.

Comment: In my mind *of* is for texts, *for* is for words. "This English-language book is the translation of that Russian book" but "whatever is the translation for cualquiera in Spanish".

Comment: Generally, though, I would just say "What is Portuguese for *whatever*?" or "What is *whatever* in Portuguese?"

Comment: To add to Unrelated's first comment, it wouldn't be "in" Portuguese, it would be "to" Portuguese, or better, "the Portuguese translation..."

Comment: Could you add a few examples please, Hugo.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Basically when I want to translate some word to another language and I ask: what's the translation of/for (word) in (language)? I want to know if I should use "of" or "for" in the sentence.

Comment: But ELU expects people asking questions to carry out and provide evidence of basic research. 'I've seen both in many texts (including this site)' should be accompanied by examples.

Comment: Well, I've searched for "translation of" and "translation for" in stack exchange and got lots of results for both, but I don't know if both are correct. Examples : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38119/translation-of-soccer-term-disarm, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372167/translation-for-buksi-hungarian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google Ngram, "translation of" has a prevalence of .0008%, while "translation for" has a prevalence of .00002%. Since "translation of" is forty times more prominent in books, I would use that, though both seem right to me.

Comment: Since neither has any useful ranking, your use of Google Ngram suggests neither has any use and sadly in that context, 40 times nothing is still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

In any case, the answer is ’qualquer coisa’ as in ’anything’ or ’não importa’ as in ’doesn't matter’. :)

But I think both sentences are correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

You prolly mean not "in" but "from" Portuguese.

Either way English grammar makes no relevant distinction. "Translation of" and "…for" have the same meaning. So might "… from" and possibly other forms.

You should find more help in English Language Learning…

Comment: Thanks and could either of those downvoters break cover at least to explain the idea? I don't mind about anyone's identity and I do feel sure neither I nor anyone else should ever be allowed to make an unsubstantiated Comment, let alone a Downvote. Please note that "neither I…"!